# System.Windows.Data Error: 40 BindingExpression path error

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So this is the code-

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid >
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" >     
                                            <Button Command="{Binding OpenWindowCommand}">         
                                               <Image Source="{StaticResource IconImage}" Width="20" Height="20" />   
                                            </Button> 
                                        </Grid>
                                    ...
```

It gives this error while running.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OpenWindowCommand' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=1217782553)'. BindingExpression:Path=OpenWindowCommand; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1217782553); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=OpenWindowCommand; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1217782553); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=OpenWindowCommand; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1217782553); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=OpenWindowCommand; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1217782553); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

I have

```
public ICommand OpenWindowCommand
{
    get
    {
           ...
    }
}
```

in the ViewModel Class, but sure why its happening.

I know there is an answer for the same question but I couldnt make it work for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Binding` is in the wrong `DataContext`. You can specify the `DataContext` by using "ElementName" or "RelativeSource" in your `Binding`:

```
<UserControl x:Name="_myUserControl" >
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Grid >
              <Grid Grid.Column="1" >     
                   <!--<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenWindowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}">  -->       
                   <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenWindowCommand, ElementName=_myUserControl}">         
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource IconImage}" Width="20" Height="20" />   
                   </Button> 
              </Grid>
 </UserControl >
```